# How to create invite a friend in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, friend, invite

I want to create the ability for a User to go to a form and put a first name and email address and send an invitation via email.

When the recipient clicks on the included link and registers, the Recipient and User are now "friends."

Is there a good tutorial to get me started on this?

Answer (score 2):

See this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations) on beta invites.

Comment: thanks, yeah, I saw that, and used that before, debating whether that's exacdtly the way I want to go...it didn't seem to retain the friend "association"...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) as an authentication solution you may take a look at [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) which add support to devise for sending invitations by email.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the email thing by using rails builtin mailer: ActionMailer

Here you are: [ActionMailer guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check [acts_as_inevitable](http://github.com/vigetlabs/acts_as_inviteable/) plugin.

Comment: Hi, so I installed the plugin and checked the code...it's not that clear what I need to do to get it going, have you used this?

Comment: Link broken - goes to 404 on github